# Can't define receiver from another package in Go

Tags: database, go, package

I'm a beginner in Golang and can't understand some concepts in this language. I like it very much, but every examples on the web are very simple and not explain the correct way of developing.
I want to configure db connection with MySQL. I create a package `dbconfig` with file dbconfig.go and package dastructure with interfaces files and another package `entity` with entities files.
This is the structure:
[[image: 1]]

**main.go:**

```
import (
    y "github.com/danyalov/shebeke/dbconfig"
    "github.com/danyalov/shebeke/routes"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "github.com/labstack/gommon/log"
)

func main() {
    db, err := y.InitDB("mysql", "root:root@tcp(localhost:3306)/dbtest?parseTime=true")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    e := routes.NewConnection(db)
    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":9898"))
}
```

**routes.go:**

```
import (
    "github.com/danyalov/shebeke/datastructure"
    y "github.com/danyalov/shebeke/dbconfig"
    "github.com/labstack/echo"
    "github.com/labstack/echo/middleware"
)

func NewConnection(db *y.DB) *echo.Echo {
    e := echo.New()
    env := Env{db}
    e.Use(middleware.Logger())
    e.Use(middleware.Recover())

    e.GET("/contracts", env.GetContracts)
    e.GET("/contract/:id", env.GetContractByID)

    return e
}

type Env struct {
    contract datastructure.Contract
}
```

**services.go:**

```
import (
    "github.com/labstack/echo"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
)

func (env *Env) GetContracts(c echo.Context) error {
    contracts, err := env.contract.GetContracts()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, &contracts)
}
```

**dbconfig.go:**

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/labstack/gommon/log"
)

type DB struct {
    *sql.DB
}

//InitDB initialize mysql database
func InitDB(driver, path string) (*DB, error) {
    db, err := sql.Open(driver, path)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Connected to DB")
    }
    return &DB{db}, err
}
```

**datastructure/contract.go:**

```
import y "github.com/danyalov/shebeke/datastructure/entity"

type Contract interface {
    GetContracts() (y.Contracts, error)
    GetContractByID(id int) (y.Contract, error)
}
```

**datastructure/entity/contract.go:**

```
import (
    "github.com/labstack/gommon/log"
    "time"
)

type Contract struct {
    ID         int       `json:"id"`
    State      string    `json:"state"`
    StartDate  time.Time `json:"start_date"`
    FinishDate time.Time `json:"finish_date"`
}

type Contracts []Contract

func (db *DB) GetContracts() (c Contracts, err error) {
    rows, err := db.Query("select * from contract")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    contract := Contract{}
    for rows.Next() {
        err = rows.Scan(&contract.ID, &contract.State, &contract.StartDate, &contract.FinishDate)
        c = append(c, contract)
    }
    return c, err
}
```

Why can't I import `DB` type from `dbconfig` package into `entity` package as a method receiver? I get `Unresolved type 'DB'` error.

This is [my working copy(Git)](https://github.com/danyalov/shebeke) of this project, I put `dbconfig.go` inside the entity, but I don't like it, I think it's incorrect place for `dbconfig` file.

What is the correct file structure for configuring db in Go? Maybe you have your own examples in Git or some tutorial?

Comment: You really should come up with a minimal example which shows your problem. You show much to much complicated code which has no relation to the problem.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can only define methods on a type defined *in that same package*.  Your `DB` type, in this case, is defined within your `dbconfig` package, so your `entity` package can't define methods on it.

In this case, your options are to make GetContracts a function instead of a method and hand it the `*dbconfig.DB` as an argument, or to invert the dependency by importing your `entity` package in `dbconfig` and write GetContracts there (as a method or function, works either way).  This second one may actually be the better option, because, from a design perspective, it breaks abstraction to have packages other than your database package creating SQL query strings.

Comment: so, I must move my GetContracts(or anothers) from entity/contract.go to dbconfig package?

Comment: Or write them as functions (not methods) within the entity package.  Your choice.  Personally, I recommend putting the database queries in the database package.

Answer (score 4):

The straightforward way to do this is to wrap the type with a type in your own package:

```golang
type MyRouterGroup struct {
    *gin.RouterGroup
}

func InitRouter() *gin.Engine {
    r := gin.Default()
    v1Group := &MyRouterGroup{r.Group("v1")}
    v1Group.MyReceiverMethod()
}
```

Comment: It's not mechanically incorrect, it's just not really the _best_ way to handle it.  It does in fact enable you to make methods, but they're not really _on_ that other type.  It falls a bit too closely to the "inheritance" design line for idiomatic Go, imo.  As with most things that get near that line, the proper answer is _usually_ to rethink the question, to determine what actually needs solved, not how to implement what one assumes is the solution.